# How to make a column filter for (key, value) for each column using ng-repeat in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

Due to large amount of apis,I have to use `(key,value)` format in `ng-repeat` to display my table. Right now, I want to also create a dynamic column filter for each column, but throw me an error: `filter: noArray`. 
Please see my example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/zichenma/rhvLndnp/

How can I create this filter? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to filter the data by typing in the text box in the first row. Smart-table can do that for you. take a look at [it](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/)

Comment: Thank you. It looks quite fit my requirement. I will dig it deeper